# How to fix Javascript associative array error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a list of images with their titles stored in an associative array. But the code only displays the last image and title in the array, in the browser not all of them.  However when I console log the values: value.title and value .image the full list is displayed in the console. I must be missing something simple any pointers would be welcome.

```
<center id="pics"></center>
    <script>
      const photos = [
        {
          title: "Landscape River",
          image: "landscape1.png",
        },
        {
          title: "Landscape Mountains",
          image: "landscape2.png",
        },
        {
          title: "Landscape Mountain Road",
          image: "landscape3.png",
        },
        {
          title: "Landscape Hills and Lake",
          image: "landscape4.png",
        },
      ];

      photos.forEach((value) => {
        console.log(value.title, value.image);
       
          document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML =
            `<img src="images/${value.image}" >` + "<br>" + value.title;
        
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: You will want to do document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML `+=` instead of just `=`. You want to append each title and image, and not reset the innerHTML every time with a new title/image if that makes sense.

Comment: @alonealgorithm, Thanks  your answer works perfectly. If you answer I can mark it has the correct answer. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Javascript does not have associative arrays, only index-based arrays. The `center` tag has been deprecated 12 years ago.

Comment: @connexo. Thanks for your input on the array, it probably explains the downvote on my question, but it’s always good to learn so thanks. As for the centre div being depreciated I just use it for quick experimental projects when testing things out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the accepted answer kind of works, it is a not a good solution, because it leads to totally unnecessary re-rendering of the DOM with every loop iteration. And that is just the performance side of the story; using `innerHTML` also is bad security-wise.

Instead, create those elements dynamically using `document.createElement`, append it to a `documentFragment`, and when the loop is done, `append` that fragment to the actual DOM.

That being said, this is what a proper solution could look like:

```js
const picsContainer = document.getElementById("pics");
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
photos.forEach(({image, title}) => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = `images/${image}`;
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  const text = document.createTextNode(title);
  fragment.append(img, br, text);        
});
picsContainer.append(fragment);
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, I really appreciate the time and effort you have taken not only to answer my question but to give a much better solution than my effort.  It also provides a great learning opportunity for me as there are concepts included here that I was unaware of. You have given me something to expand my understanding of Javascript and I am very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do `document.getElementById("pics").innerHTML +=` instead of just `=`. You want to append each title and image, and not reset the innerHTML every time with a new title/image if that makes sense. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks I spent ages not understanding my error, your answer made perfect sense.

Comment: While this kind of works, it is a bad solution, because it leads to totally unnecessary re-rendering of the DOM with every loop iteration. Instead, create those elements dynamically using `document.createElement`, append it to a `documentFragment`, and when the loop is done, append the `content` of that `fragment` to the actual DOM. And that is just the performance side of the story; using `innerHTML` also is bad security-wise.

Comment: *and not reset the innerHTML every time with a new title/image* which is exactly what your code also does.

Comment: @ connexo. Wow! Thanks, sounds like really helpful and useful advice, I will do some more research and go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @connexo That's great to know. You're absolutely right that my solution will re-render the render tree during each iteration. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @codestruggler I would mark connexo's answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: @ alonealgorithm. Thanks, I am glad you said that, I will.  You answered my question to what I did wrong, with my code as I had written it. @connexo  takes it to the next level. Thanks